# PreparedStatments and ResultSet JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I am working with preparedStmts and resultSets for the first time on an assignment, when I run this program, it runs to completion, but it does not add anything to the sql table. We must use those two together and I have scoured the internet to try to figure out how to get this to work, but am still having problems. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
<%
int result = 0;
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
  conn = JdbcManager.getConnection();
  String sqlcmd = "select * from APP.STOCK_TBL";
  stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlcmd, rs.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, rs.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, rs.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
  String symbol = request.getParameter("SYMBOL");
  String name = request.getParameter("NAME");
  rs = stmt.executeQuery();

  while(rs.next()){

      if(rs.getString("SYMBOL").equals( rs.getString(1))){

          rs.updateString("SYMBOL", rs.getString("SYMBOL"));
          rs.updateString("NAME", rs.getString("NAME"));
          rs.updateRow();

          }
      if(!(rs.getString("SYMBOL").equals(rs.getString(1)))){

            if(rs.isAfterLast()){

                rs.moveToInsertRow();
                rs.updateString(1, rs.getString("SYMBOL"));
                rs.updateString(2, rs.getString("NAME"));
                rs.insertRow();

            }
          }
      }
%>
```

Edit* Sorry forgot to explain issue, when I run this program, it runs to completion, but it does not add anything to the sql table.
Edit** Updated code

Comment: Maybe you should explain what problems you're having.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain the issue, I edited and posted it on the bottom.

Comment: Why would a SELECT statement *add* data to the table?  You sure your query is correct for what you want to accomplish?

Comment: How about change your `if(rs.getString("SYMBOL") != rs.getString(1)){` to `else`. I guess the same column value can not read twice, maybe.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: As @Kayaman indicated, you are comparing Strings incorrectly.

Comment: I totally forgot about that and corrected it and now when I run it, it still does not add or update. Edited code above for clarity of changes.

Comment: Your code makes zero sense. Why are you updating columns with the same value those columns already have?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel , to explain further what this web application does, the user submits a stocks ticker and the name of the stock. When they submit, it is suppose to search the SQL DB if it runs across the ticker symbol is a match it is suppose to update the name of the symbol, if it does not exist it is suppose to insert the symbol and name. That is why it seems redundant, but I feel like I am on the right track to it.

Comment: Updating a column with the value it already has is useless and only has unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, that is a very good point, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

you could use this example in order to insert values to the sql table:

```
String name, last_name, phone;
PreparedStatement stmt = conn
                        .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `admins` ( `name`, `last_name`,`phone`) VALUES (?,?,?)");

                stmt.setString(1, name); 

                stmt.setString(2, lastname);

                stmt.setString(3, phone);  stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: yes I did that in a previous assignment, but we have to use resultSet with the preparedStatement with this one, thanks for the suggestion!